# How do I draw a chart with lines through various points, using matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python. I borrowed this code from an example, and put in my own numbers:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(1, 9, 'rs', 2, 8, 'bs', 7, 3, 'g^', 9, 1, 'r^')
plt.title('Chart of 4 companies')
plt.axis([0, 12, 0, 12])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

This works great, it shows me a chart, and it shows 4 points on the chart. But is it possible to show the line going from point [0,0] to these lines? I wanted to make a point about cosine similarity, but I am failing badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want a straight line from (0,0) to a point (x,y) you can plot it simply via

```
plt.plot([0,x],[0,y])
```

So the whole code may look like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(1, 9, 'rs', 2, 8, 'bs', 7, 3, 'g^', 9, 1, 'r^')
plt.plot([0,1], [0,9], 'r')
plt.plot([0,2], [0,8], 'b')
plt.plot([0,7], [0,3], 'g')
plt.plot([0,9], [0,1], 'r')
plt.title('Chart of 4 companies')
plt.axis([0, 12, 0, 12])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]